# magento 2.0.5 to magento2.1, Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned

Tags: magento, upgrade

I am using Magento 2.0.5. When I run the composer update command, it's showing the following warning:

> Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use friends ofphp/php-cs-fixer instead.
>
> Writing lock file
>
> Generating autoload files

Who can help me?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this is  friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer. You can have a look at [this link](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer)

If you want to remove this warning, you can open the composer.json file, then in "require-dev" find "fapbot/php-cs-fixer" and replace it with "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer". Then you can run the composer update.